# In Python, what is the reason for the blank line while writing to a textfile as per code mentioned below?

Tags: python

When we use print statement as mentioned below

```
print("This is Python \r\nProgramming")
```

Output

```
This is Python
Programming
```

Here there is no blank line in output

But when we try to write the same string in a Text File on windows OS, as per code shown below, a blank line gets inserted in generated text-file

```
myfile = open("New_File.txt",'w')
myfile.write("This is Python \r\nProgramming")
myfile.close()
```

Output

```
This is Python

Programming
```

What is the logic for this blank line while writing on a textfile?

Comment: Tried to duplicate this, but in the second case I do not get the blank line in the file. Edit: I am on a MacOS. I suspect it might be something about windows and the \r

Comment: When you're writing a file, ```\n``` is translated to a platform-appropriate line break. (So in Windows it will become ```\r\n```.) The extra ```\r``` in your string is superfluous

Comment: No blank line in MacOS. No idea why it happened in Windows

Comment: Since the file was opened with `newline=None` (the default for `open`), the `\n` you are writing is converted to `\r\n` on Windows. However you are viewing your file may be interpreting the resulting `\r\r\n` as a blank line.

Comment: Everything is a matter of interpretation. Even a text file consists of 0's and 1's. So Python determines how to handle new-lines but so does the text editor in which you open the file for viewing. In Notepad++ for example, you can choose how to interpret new lines.